# SSIS Foreach file enumerator Not picking up files once deployed

Tags: sql-server, foreach, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-agent

I have a package that loads CSV files from a folder, I have setup a foreach file enumarator to loop through the directory and assigns the files that starts with "Example*.csv" including the extention.

The package runs fine in SSDT but once i deploy and run it through the agent job does not load anything and the jobs runs successfully. I have removed the Foreach loop and connected the Flat file connector to one file and it works perfectly .

Please assist I am new to this.
[image][image]

Expression passsed to Flat File connection manager :
FolderLocation = "\Sharedrive\Business\Company-info
[image]

Comment: File system permissions of the sql server agent account and or the proxy it is running the job step under. If you look in the SSISDB for warnings/information events, you'll see one that indicates it found no files which also shows up when the account doesn't have permissions

Comment: Rereading `connected the Flat file connector to one file` Is that one file on the file share or is it local to the deployed server?

Comment: It is one of the files i have on the shared drive. the same location the for each loop is looking...

Comment: And the single file that works, is that executed from the same sql agent job, location and proxy as the one that picks no files?

Comment: Yes it does, same Sql server agent Job, same proxy and same location.

Comment: Could you update your question with the expressions on your flat file connection manager? What about the log in the SSISDB for an execution that found no files, does it reflect no file found?

Comment: Thanks @billinkc I have updated the question.No it does not reflect a file not found warning really confusing.

Comment: I think we're getting closer. The flat file connection manager has an expression of `@[User::FileLocation] + "\\" + @[User::File]`  @[User::File] is populated with Name and Extension from the foreach enumerator so foo.csv, foo2.csv. Where does @[User::FileLocation] get set? Try this, create a new variable called FullFilePath and have it be the expression on the Flat File Connection Manager and then have the FFCM's expression just be @[User::FullFilePath]  You can then add a script task inside the Loop to [log value](https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2016/04/biml-script-task-test-for-echo.html)